# How to remove square brackets [] from R data frame without regex?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, stringr

I am importing a csv using R to create a dataframe from this csv. In the csv file, there are some characters I want to eliminate.

`mydf$V1 <- str_replace_all(mydf$V1, "'", "")`

I was able to get rid of single quotes in the above way, but I'm not able to remove square brackets. I don't want to use Pandas or regex, is there a way to do this using basic R, dplyr/tidyverse/stringr, or a similar library?

Comment: what do you mean by not using pandas? This is R and not python you just need `gsub('[', '', mydf$V1, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: The equivalent in stringr would be `str_replace_all(mydf$V1,fixed("["),"")`. But it will be easier to remove both forms at the same time with a regex like `\\[|\\]`.

Comment: my bad, I thought pandas was an option in R. also, gsub didn't work for me for some reason, the brackets are still there.

Comment: using str_replace_all like that worked, thanks joran!

Comment: Can you clarify why you don't want to use regex?

Comment: @BenBolker I *think* they mean they don't want to use unix command line regex (e.g. grep) or Pandas, but presumably regex within R is fine since they specified using stringr for the problem,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat mysterious, but

```r
gsub("[][]","", x)
```

will do it (i.e., remove `[` and `]`). The outer square brackets are interpreted  as defining a set of characters; the inner square brackets are the set to remove. Putting the inner square brackets in the 'correct' order (`[[]]`) doesn't work presumably because the inner `[]` is interpreted as part of a special like `[:alpha:]`?

This regex does *not* work in `stringr::str_remove()` ("Missing closing bracket on a bracket expression"), but

```r
stringr::str_remove_all(x,"[\\[\\]]")
```

does. (The double-backslashes are required because R uses single-backslash to identify special characters like newline (`\n`) etc..)

In principle it should be possible to use the relatively new "raw strings" feature in R to simplify the expression (i.e. use regex pattern `r"[\[\]]"` instead of `"[\\[\\]]"`, but I seem to be discovering lots of weird interactions between that and the regex machinery (unless I'm doing something wrong/being sloppy, which is always a possibility ...)

If you really don't want to use regular expressions then

```r
gsub(fixed = TRUE, "[", "",
   gsub(fixed = TRUE, "]", "", x)
)
```

or

```r
x |> str_remove_all(fixed("[")) |> str_remove_all(fixed("]"))
```

should work.

Comment: Although that is using `regex` and OP does not want to use `regex`

Comment: I'm particularly amused that "[[]]" doesn't work, though!